# Add Parse SDK to your Android Project and using parse sdk project file in android version 3.4.1 or 3.4.2

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

### How we download parse SDK file for update version. Old version project does not work properly in the project file. and also what change want in the android studio project file to used parse activity.

#### [Look the problem comes in an older version or any other solution have to resolve this please tell me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4qZd.png)

## Also What changes want in the project to run parse server project please tell me

#### send me the link of the project file which I want to include update android version

Comment: Can you please confirm that you have followed all steps in the link below? https://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#getting-started

Comment: Installation
Step 1: Download Parse-SDK-Android

that step was not completed perfectly. because currently. I using android 3.4.1
that version SDK I can't find it.
Can you send me the link of SDK which was a support that android version?

when I using old version SDK he gives me an error.

Comment: Unfortunately Parse Android SDK only supports Android >= 4.0. For Android 3.4.1, you will need to use the [REST API](https://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/) or the [GraphQL API](http://docs.parseplatform.org/graphql/guide/) directly (without using the SDK).

Comment: **Android >= 4.0 ??** I don't understand then which android version supported parse SDK

Comment: Any version superior to 4.0 which means any version launched after October 2011. You can see the complete list here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#Android_4.0_Ice_Cream_Sandwich_ITL41D_(API_14)

Comment: **Thank you** for solving my problem. And sorry for inconvenient.

Comment: No problem. You're welcome.